# EXCEL Highlight Lowest value in A row excluding emptycell

Tags: excel

How to exclude an empty cell to be highlighted in the cell. This is my formula so far.

```
=C1=MIN($C1,$E1,$G1,$I1)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `=AND(C1<>"",C1=MIN($C1,$E1,$G1,$I1))`

Comment: This highlights all the empty.

Comment: I just did a test on my computer and verified that this does not highlight the empties, it specifically ignores them

Comment: My error. It does really work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition that checks if the cell is blank.

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C1)),C1=MIN($C1,$E1,$G1,$I1))
```

[image]

Also, you may want to consider applying the conditional formatting only to the rows with data, not the whole million of rows. CF takes time to process and too much of it, applied to too many cells, may result in slow workbooks.

Comment: I have an additional question. I want to get the column name of the lowest value. How can that be done? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200259/excel-get-the-column-header-of-the-lowest-value-in-the-row