# EXCEL Get the column header of the lowest value in the row

Tags: excel

With the help of [teylyn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199865/excel-highlight-lowest-value-in-a-row-excluding-emptycell/37200033#37200033) in my previous question, the lowest value in the row are successfully highlighted. How to get the column letter to be displayed in the last column?

FROM

[image]

TO

[image]

Comment: How do intend to handle it when the MIN is in more than one column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=Left(if($C4=Min($C4:$I4),$C$3&" & ","")&if($E4=Min($C4:$I4),$E$3&" & ","")&if($G4=Min($C4:$I4),$G$3&" & ","")&if($I4=Min($C4:$I4),$I$3&" & ",""),LEN(if($C4=Min($C4:$I4),$C$3&" & ","")&if($E4=Min($C4:$I4),$E$3&" & ","")&if($G4=Min($C4:$I4),$G$3&" & ","")&if($I4=Min($C4:$I4),$I$3&" & ",""))-3)
```

Its ugly...really ugly.  But it does work.  Put that monstrosity in J4 and copy down.

where to begin with the description, I thought ugly and monstrosity covered it!  Basically what the whole formula is doing is checking each number in the row to detemine if it is the minimum in the row.  When that condition is true, it returns the value in the header row for that number and tacks on a " & " to it.  It then moves on to the next column and performs the same check and adds the results to the previous column.  When a number is not the minimum it adds "" to the results which is nothing.  After going through all the results and building up a string that will end in "&" we pull the left side of the string, by the length of the string minus 3 characters to remove that last " & ".

### Proof of concept

[image: Proof of concept]

Comment: It would have been a cleaner solution had there not been a need for the &.  I am not a fan of this solution as it is very specific to the data showing and is very "verbose" in terms of a formula as it is repeating itself.  I am sure there is a sumproduct aggregate index type solution which is more efficient/concise.

Comment: Why go with `LEFT`? Put the `" & "` in front and use `MID` like `=MID(IF($C4=MIN($C4:$I4)," & "&$C$3,"")&IF($E4=MIN($C4:$I4)," & "&$E$3,"")&IF($G4=MIN($C4:$I4)," & "&$G$3,"")&IF($I4=MIN($C4:$I4)," & "&$I$3,""),4,20)` ;)

Comment: At the other hand, you also could do a `COUNTIF` with `MIN` like `COUNTIF($C4:$I4,MIN($C4:$I4))` and then `*4-3` to get the length a bit shorter :)

Comment: @DirkReichel go mid when you could go RIGHT?  and as for the countif, well its nearly 4 am here and my brain checked our about 3 hours ago...my mind was not on a countif....actually I cant wrap my mind around the count if at the moment.

Comment: @DirkReichel No offence taken what so ever, and that is exactly why I ask if you would prefer to have small nuances in wording like that pointed out or would just prefer to let it be.  Ich spreche kine Deutch.  or is it Ich spreche nicht Deuth gern.  I was born in Lahr, but I failed intro to german in university.  I would say post your answer, especially the countif one.  I will read it about 8 hours when I wake up.  8) Guten Tag!  And by the way your English is pretty darned good!

Comment: "Ich spreche keine Deutsch." or "Ich kann kein Deutsch" would be the correct way here. And wow... I really wrote "English is not *your* mother tongue"... looks like a copy/paste error (while copy/paste wasn't used at all)... (T_T)

Answer (score 1):

Like said in the comments of Forward Ed's answer, you could shorten the `LEN`-part with `COUNTIF` which would look like this:

```
=LEFT(IF($C4=MIN($C4:$I4),$C$3&" & ","")&IF($E4=MIN($C4:$I4),$E$3&" & ","")&IF($G4=MIN($C4:$I4),$G$3&" & ","")&IF($I4=MIN($C4:$I4),$I$3&" & ",""),COUNTIF($C4:$I4,MIN($C4:$I4))*4-3)
```

Still I would prefer the `MID` solution to (partially) skip any check of length like this:

```
=MID(IF($C4=MIN($C4:$I4)," & "&$C$3,"")&IF($E4=MIN($C4:$I4)," & "&$E$3,"")&IF($G4=MIN($C4:$I4)," & "&$G$3,"")&IF($I4=MIN($C4:$I4)," & "&$I$3,""),4,20)
```

The way it works should be pretty obvious. However, if there are any questions left, just ask :)

Answer (score 0):

To return the header of a row containing the minimum value in a specific range, you can use the following Excel formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$Z$1, 1, MATCH(MIN(A2:Z2), A2:Z2, 0))
```

Here's a breakdown of how this formula works:

1. `$A$1:$Z$1` represents the header row in your Excel sheet. Adjust this range to match the actual range of your header row.
2. `A2:Z2` represents the data range where you want to find the minimum value in each row. Adjust this range to match the data in your Excel sheet.
3. `MIN(A2:Z2)` calculates the minimum value in the specified data range.
4. `MATCH(MIN(A2:Z2), A2:Z2, 0)` finds the position (column number) of the minimum value within the data range.
5. `INDEX($A$1:$Z$1, 1, ...)` returns the header corresponding to the column number found in step 4. It retrieves the header from the header row.

Enter this formula in the cell where you want to display the header of the row with the minimum value. Replace `$A$1:$Z$1` and `A2:Z2` with the actual ranges in your worksheet.